# Can HealthKit tell me how fresh the data is?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, healthkit

I'm working on a widget that shows a user's daily steps, so it asks HK for that data. I've noticed that sometimes HK lags in showing the most up-to-date info, so I'd like to display something like "**300 steps today (as of 2:31pm)**" in the widget.

I can get the step count, no problem. But can HealthKit give me the age of the data I'm asking for (or the most recent timestamp on that data)?

Answer (score 1):

Each `HKSample` has a `startDate` and `endDate` property. You can use the most recent sample's `endDate` to determine how up-to-date the total step count is.